# Can Azure Resource Manager inventory plugin dynamically find VMs based on a substring of a resource group names (in include_vm_resource_groups)

Tags: azure, ansible-inventory

How can Azure Resource Manager inventory plugin dynamically finds VMs based on a substring of a resource group names (in include_vm_resource_groups)

I can get a list of VMs using the full resource group name in the include_vm_resource_groups, but not when using a partial\substring of the resource group name.

Please provide an example
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, sub-strings cannot be used.

As a workaround i put a filter on the *hosts* variable in the playbook file

```
# This is an explanation of the following command:
  # 1. Find the hostname of Ansible host using lookup("pipe","hostname").
  # 2. Pipe the result and replace "-management-ansible" with "_cluster". E.g of output: ddd-dev001-01_cluster 
  # 3. Pipe the result and replace "-" with "_". E.g of output:  ddd_dev001_01_cluster
  # 4. Append the result to hosts group "tag_workspace_". E.g of output:  tag_workspace_ddd_dev001_01_cluster
  # Note hyphens are not accepted in host group names.
  hosts: tag_workspace_{{ lookup("pipe","hostname") | regex_replace('-management-ansible', '_cluster') |  regex_replace('-', '_') }}
```